# Box-blight or just the effects of winter

Tags: diagnosis, boxwood

I have some small box-trees which start to have some yellow leaves on the top of some branches. Is this the start of box-blight or just the effects of winter. We have some low temperatures (down to -5 C) here and snow (20-30cm).

Please advise with the help of the pictures below. (Click to enlarge)

[image]
                        [image] [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like winter burn to me based on:

- absence of circular necrotic spots on the leaves
- boxwood blight (Cylindrocladium buxicola (syn C. pseudonaviculatum))should be less active during winter months as it is usually drier and colder
- absence of dark or blight on the stems

From [here](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/hortline.asp?code=3959) winter burn is described as:

> Winter damage occurs on boxwoods (Buxus sp.) when unseasonably warm
>   winter days are followed by freezing temperatures. During the warm
>   period, the plant begins to come out of dormancy and the cambium or
>   conductive tissue begins to fill with additional water. When the
>   temperature drops below freezing, the water freezes. The expanding ice
>   splits the tissue resulting in death of the affected tissue. Cold, dry
>   winds pull moisture from the affected branch resulting in a
>   freeze-dried, "freezer burn" effect. Depending upon conditions, whole
>   plants, just sections of a plant or only the tips of branches may be
>   affected

Boxwood blight is described in detail [here](http://soilplantandpest.utk.edu/pdffiles/presentations/Boxblight.pdf).

- It is considered to be endemic in Europe and other areas of the world.
- Warm humid weather with abundant leaf litter to act as a source of infection promote the growth of the disease
- it can attack cuttings, containerized plants or well established plants
- fungal controls only give some relief

As is typical with many fungal diseases keeping the ground clear of debris, using a mulch to reduce soil splashing on leaves and good cultural practices will go some ways to preventing this.